# Can we change the `New Query` name template?

Tags: azure-data-studio

Currently, AzureDataStudio creates `New Query` like so:
[image]

The above picture shows two tabs but each are for different servers named `dev` and `qa`. It would be nice to name the `New Query` with more useful information like `SQLQuery_1 - dev` and `SQLQuery_2 - qa`.